# Placing triangle left of proof

Tags: theorems

I have an image that I'm trying to put to the left of my proof.

I'm using

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
```

But maybe only `\usepackage{graphicx}` is relevant?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that shows your problem. This would help us help you, since otherwise we don't know which packages etc. you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an image to the left using `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, graphicx, calc}
\usepackage{mwe, lipsum} % for example only
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5in}
\includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-.5in}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way to stretch it vertically and horisontally?

Comment: @perpersson You can stretch horizontally by changing the .5in to whatever you desire and can stretch vertically by adding `height=2in` (or your desired value) to the `\includegraphics` command (ie. `\includegraphics[width=.5in, height=2in]{example-image-a}`)

Comment: Very, very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can place your picture in one `minipage` and place the proof in an adjacent `minipage`, with the total width of the two equaling `\linewidth`. I used a `tikzpicture` to create my image, but you could just as easily use `\includegraphics` with the `graphicx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
Triangles have three sides.
\end{thm}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0)--(.5,2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\end{minipage}% Need this % to prevent a space
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{minipage}
\strut

\strut
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```